# Linking custom taps to existing bottles in bintray

Tags: docker, homebrew, docker-machine

As it usually happens sometimes you get stuck with older version of some software. But you still want to be able to install it seamlessly using homebrew. In my company we are stuck with old version of docker so I created my own tap from the old version of docker Formula.

```
class Docker191 < Formula
  desc "Pack, ship and run any application as a lightweight container"
  homepage "https://www.docker.com/"
  url "https://github.com/docker/docker.git",
      :tag => "v1.9.1",
      :revision => "a34a1d598c6096ed8b5ce5219e77d68e5cd85462"
  revision 1

  head "https://github.com/docker/docker.git"

  bottle do
    cellar :any_skip_relocation
    root_url "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles"
    sha256 "fe02c921afd6863be441b85ae069e24b7c5b13e97615b47c994ea8064e082bf1" => :el_capitan
    sha256 "8a3137f5d6155491e9c4833d80ca819d8bf6d31f38595be713baed06f5283c92" => :yosemite
    sha256 "282f987005f81d9a82269827b66aa1044dfbd8645c23845d59e21aad93dc99e0" => :mavericks
  end

  option "without-completions", "Disable bash/zsh completions"

  depends_on "go" => :build

  conflicts_with "docker", :because => "Differing version of the same formula"

  def install
    ENV["AUTO_GOPATH"] = "1"
    ENV["DOCKER_CLIENTONLY"] = "1"

    system "hack/make.sh", "dynbinary"

    build_version = build.head? ? File.read("VERSION").chomp : version
    bin.install "bundles/#{build_version}/dynbinary/docker-#{build_version}" => "docker"

    if build.with? "completions"
      bash_completion.install "contrib/completion/bash/docker"
      fish_completion.install "contrib/completion/fish/docker.fish"
      zsh_completion.install "contrib/completion/zsh/_docker"
    end
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/docker", "--version"
  end
end
```

It all builds fine from the source but I was wondering whether it is possible to pull the bottles already built and available in bintray instead of building from source.

I tried to do it by adding

> root_url "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles"

But because my Formula name is Docker191 instead of just Docker it tries to pull from nonexistent path

> ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/docker191-1.9.1_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz

instead of

> ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/docker-1.9.1_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz

Is there a way to fix the bottle name as well? I cannot change the name of formula to Docker because I need multiple versions to be available.

Comment: I just ran into this. I renamed the bottles to suit and hosted on my own git repository but ran into other issues. https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2373